# How to transform string to array in angularjs's html

Tags: angularjs, filter

```js
.filter('privateip',function() {
    return function(p) {
        p.split(',');
        return p
    }
})
```

```html
<tr ng-repeat="ins in  instances">
  <td ><input type="checkbox" ng-model="icheckedList[ins.id]" ng-required="{{needOneList}}" ng-checked="all" one-least></td>
  <td><span ng-bind="ins.name"></span></td>
  <td><table><tr ng-repeat="p in ins.private_ip|privateip"></tr></table></td>
  <td ng-bind="ins.public_ip"></td>
</tr>
```

ins.private_ip is a string (like '192.168.1.1,192,168.1.2,192.168.1.8') which i want to transform to array, how can i do that  use the filter or any way you recommend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return split result:

```
.filter('privateip',function() {
    return function(p) {
        return p.split(',');
    }
});
```

Strings a immutable, which means that `p.split(',')` doesn't mutate `p`, but rather returns new value (array in this case).

Comment: It doesn't work...  And I want to ask that in ng-repeat="p in ins.private_ip | privateip" the filter's parameter is  private_ip?    I am a newbie ...

Comment: It should work. Here is a demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/yaq4qJ2Zj7WzzH7D7ikE?p=preview. And `privateip` filter doesn't take any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

you can `ngRepeat` over a function which return an array:

```
<td><table><tr ng-repeat="p in splitIps(ins.private_ip)"></tr></table></td>

//controller
$scope.splitIps = function(ip){
    return ip.split('.');
}
```

Comment: I had try it  but when the ip='192.168.1.1'  the result that ip was splited to [ ' ',' ' ] , it is so strange...   but in chrome's  console  the split result  is nomal ,how can i do to solve the problem?

Comment: its hard to tell... make sure the raw string doesn't contain any whitespaces or line breaks. you could use `trim()` to remove whitespaces before split it

Comment: OH   ,, it's my reason  ,  I am  so sorry I forget to change something  ,thank you ~~